# Django 2.1 Test Issue

Tags: django, django-tests

I'm learning Django, I had several years developing with Python and decided to start to check this Framework. And I'm getting an weird responses. I'm writing a TestCase, which works perfectly outside Test.

That is the code:

```
class BoardTopicsTests(TestCase):
    # Hago las acciones necesarias para empezar el test
    def setUp(self):
        self.board = Board(name="Django", description="Django board.")
        # self.board.save()

    # Compruebo el status_code 200
    def test_board_topics_view_status_code(self):
        # self.board.save()
        url = reverse("board_topics", kwargs={"pk":1})
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    # Compruebo el status_code 404
    def test_board_topics_view_not_found_status_code(self):
        url = reverse("board_topics", kwargs={"pk" : 99})
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)

    # Compruebo que resuelve bien el board
    def test_board_topics_url_resolves_board_topics_views(self):
        view = resolve("/boards/1/")
        self.assertEqual( view.func.__name__, BoardTopics.as_view().__name__ )
```

If I save the board in setUp the method test_board_topics_view_status_code returns 404, if I save the board inside the method it returns 200 and pass the test.

I think I'm missing something because I think it have to work saving from setUp method!

Please, can somebody help with that? It's just for learning purposes because I want to know what's happening there.

If I do print(self.board.id) inside test_board_topics_view_status_code it returns 1 as it supposed to be.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I've researched a bit more and found the solution:

If you want to setup TEST data you must use:

        @classmethod
        def setUpTestData(cls):
                #Some actions to store data

The setUp method must be used for example to login some user.

Thank you anyway for your time! :P

Comment: Please post your answer so others may benefit.

Answer (score -1):

After researching a bit I came with the solution:

```
@classmethod
def setUpTestData(cls):
    Board.objects.create(name="Django", description="Django board.")
```

Instead of:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.board = Board(name="Django", description="Django board.")
    self.board.save()
```

It works BUT I'm trying to do the same with another class and the 404 still returns... In that particular TestCase works, in another ones dont,oO

I'm researching a bit more, I will write back if I found the "ultimate" solution hehehe.

UPDATE:

Well at the end I found the problem! The solution is the next one:

```
@classmethod
def setUpTestData(cls):
    self.board = Board.objects.create(name="Django", description="Django board.")

# Compruebo el status_code 200
def test_board_topics_view_status_code(self):
    url = reverse("board_topics", kwargs={"pk":self.board.pk})
    response = self.client.get(url)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Note that in kwargs the value of pk is **self.board.pk** insteadof (and here where the error was) **hardcoded 1** because we dont know if the PK would be 1!!! Oh that silly error took me one night without sleep.

So at the end we can resume in the next:

- **Use setUpTestData instead setUp to add Data**
- **Dont hardcode pk, store the object you already inserted and return the pk**

Hope the answer helps!

Your's S3yk0